# In wpf how to access window.resources in usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls, resources, collectionviewsource

I have a child usercontrol and I am having trouble accessing its parent usercontrol's resources. The resource is a collectionViewSource and its source is set in the code behind of the parent usercontrol, the source is set to a query result from LINQ to SQL. Both usercontrols are defined in their own xaml file. I tried using DynamicResource and it complained saying it needs to be used with a DepenednecyProperty or so...

**parent usercontrol**:

```
...
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="UsageTypeSource"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
```

**child usercontrol**:

```
...
<ComboBox Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,1,0,0" x:Name="cbxUsage"
          Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="186"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=UsageType, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedValuePath="ID"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Usage}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UsageTypeSource}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Type"/>
...
```

The error I am getting is 'The resource "UsageTypeSource" could not be resolved'

Can you provide the proper way to access the resource

Thanks in advance
Ash

Comment: It's not related to your problem, but does it really make sense to bind both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`?

Comment: @Clemens it does on some situations, I don't know specifically this one.

Comment: I initially had it using SelectedValue and forgot to remove it, thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ItemsSource="{DynamicResource UsageTypeSource}}"/>
```

Comment: @Clemens not really, he's probably doing `{Binding Source={DynamicResource ..}}` which is not allowed, because the Source property of the `Binding` class is not a DP.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<UserControl.Resources> ... </UserControl.Resources>
```

Use

```
<Control.Resources> ... </Control.Resources>
```